# Suitelet doesn't set the child sublist record values

Tags: netsuite

I created a suitelet that should set the value into a child sublist record. However, this not happens. I attached a screenshot of my code.

I used a for loop to get the value from the sublist created by suitelet. However, seems that the value is not read or set.[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1V3u.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAhOS.png)

Comment: post the text not an image, also in the picture you are only getting values, there are no `setSublistValue()` calls or something like that